# Viability of generators and electromagnetics based solely on ionic liquids

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-induction, electronics, ions

The background to this question lies in the science fiction novel "The Day the Machines Stopped" by Christopher Anvil (1964), where somehow an experiment gone wrong causes the laws of physics to locally change so that metals stop conducting electricity in the vicinity of the Earth. **This question does not concern any such actual scenario, but is only inspired by it.**

Since in the book the ionic conduction of biological life was somehow largely unaffected, I began questioning if, in our reality, replacements for modern electronic circuits based on metallic conduction and semiconductor physics could be created instead only using ionic fluids, and what would be the major challenges.

It seems to me that ionic fluid contained in insulating tubes could replace metallic wires in many situations. Basic things like mechanical switches (and even the more complicated commutator of a dynamo) could be implemented by various mechanical "tube swappers". Inductance, and electromagnetism would work in an analogous way, so both dynamos and solenoids should be possible. Am I correct?

Comment: Any time you're talking about electric current carried by the motion of ions, you're talking about electro _chemistry._ Any time you're talking about chemistry, you're talking about changes in the chemical composition of different components of the system. The engineering gets complicated. What you're describing is a generalization of how electric batteries work, and as far as I've been able to discern, the design of _practical_ electric batteries involves a good dose of occult, black magic.

Comment: @SolomonSlow My impression is that electrochemistry is what happens at the anodes and cathodes of the typical systems, but what I propose in the question is, as far as I can tell, "pure ionic conduction" where the local ionic composition would remain stable, just like the total local charge in any region of a metallic conductor remains effectively zero. (OK, I see that I mentioned capacitance and that might be a problem --- I'll edit it out, thanks!).

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer. I can't put pictures in a proper *comment.*

---

> electrochemistry...happens at the anodes and cathodes... what I propose...is..."pure ionic conduction"

I'm picturing an experiment. Two hand-built, iron-core transformers, connected as shown:

[image]

The red loop would be plastic tubing, filled with your ionic solution. No electrodes. Completely sealed. I don't imagine I'm going to build one for myself, but it would be fascinating to see how much power could be transmitted in this way and, to measure how much power might be lost to resistance in the liquid loop.

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of system I'm asking about. Thanks for making it more clear to anyone looking at the question --- not that it seems to have generated much interest.